# Android View View XML Programmatically

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to debug a view that I'm creating programmatically. I'd like to be able to see what the exact XML is of the view after it's created.

Really I'd like to be be able to do something like `Log.d(TAG,view.toString())`

And get an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="sampleapp.example.com.tr221test.MainActivity">

    <Button android:id="@+id/surveyButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Survey!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anyway I can programmatically see what the xml is of a view?

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes?

Comment: Indeed. I'm pretty sure that I have messed up the order of the additions of some views - trying to re-create an existing view programmatically.

Comment: See CommonsWare's answer for links to appropriate tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in for that. You would have to write your own `View`-hierarchy-to-XML code or see if somebody has a library for that.

Or, use [Android Studio's layout inspector](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector).

Or, [use `uiautomatorviewer`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html#setup).

Or, [use Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/).

Comment: Layout inspector is a nice new tool! I don't suppose there's any easy way to copy that over as XML? :)

Comment: @TomHammond: Not that I am aware of. Stetho's output is XML, but more in an attempt to get a layout to appear to be valid HTML for Chrome's Dev Tools to handle.